# Merge based on column names

Tags: r, merge, names

I have the following data.frame:

```
> head(y)

 depth value   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
 1 7 -82 -81 -80 -79 -78 -78 -77
 1 5 -82 -81 -80 -79 -78 -78 -77
 1 5 -82 -81 -80 -79 -78 -78 -77
 1 2 -82 -81 -80 -79 -78 -78 -77
 1 2 -82 -81 -80 -79 -78 -78 -77
 1 1 -82 -81 -80 -79 -78 -78 -77
```

I need to merge the data.frame based on the values of “value” column and get the corresponding value from “1”:“7” columns. 
I would like to get the following result:

```
depth value   merged_value
1 7 -77
1 5 -78
1 5 -78
1 2 -81
1 2 -81
1 1 -82
```

I am asking this because I have millions of rows and working with classic loops is too slow. 
Thanks in advance!
Jon

Comment: `?data.table::melt`

Answer (score 1):

I am completely redoing this answer:

In R, you don't need to loop over matrices or data.frames. R works inherently vectorized. So let's pick out the correct column with a vector.

To select *as a matrix* from a matrix, we have to subset with a matrix.
Compare the following. `vals` is the subset of values you want to "merge":

```
vals <- as.matrix(y[,3:9])
vals[y[,2]]
```

and compare to 
    cbind(1:nrow(vals), y[,2])
    vals[x]

Do you see the difference?

Now put the right lines together:

```
vals <- as.matrix(y[,3:9])
x <- cbind(1:nrow(vals), y[,2])
cbind(y[,1:2], vals[x])
```

Or a slightly improved edition:

```
x <- cbind(1:nrow(y), y[,2]+2)
cbind(y[,1:2], y[x])
```

Comment: Hi MrGumble. with your solution I produce a larger database and I must filter it afterwards... I need just one value for each matching between  the value in column "value" and columns "1":"7". As i showed at my ideal result...

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```r
> y |> 
+     pivot_longer(-(1:2), values_to = 'merged_value') |> 
+     filter(as.numeric(name) == value) |> 
+     select(depth, value, merged_value)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  depth value merged_value
  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
1     1     7          -77
2     1     5          -78
3     1     5          -78
4     1     2          -81
5     1     2          -81
6     1     1          -82
```